# add vertical colored lines to seekbar background drawable

Tags: android, seekbar

How do I dynamically add individual vertical colored lines to a seekbar's progress bar?

I already have the progress.xml, progress_fill.xml and background_fill files created as individual drawables, allowing me to customize my seekbar to some extent.  But the individual vertical lines may need to be drawn in many different colors and at any point on the seekbar, depending on the situation.  They can't be set in the XML layout files.

I guess I need to be programmatically writing little colored rects to the background_fill.xml drawable (my progress_fill has been set to mostly transparent).

How do I do write those litte rects programmatically to my background_fill.xml drawable?

I did something similar in a TextView, in that I used a SpannableStringBuilder and an ImageSpan to write the little rects into a TextView.  But I don't see that as being available for the seekbar widget.

Answer (score 2):

Did this by extending the SeekBar widget.  Two steps: first, create a new class called CustomSeekBar to extend the SeekBar:

```
package com.example.seekbar;

class CustomSeekBar extends SeekBar {

public CustomSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    private Paint paintRect = new Paint();
    paintRect.setColor(Color.rgb(142, 196, 0));

    private Rect audioRect = new Rect();
    audioRect.set(5, 7, 4, 18);

    canvas.drawRect(audioRect, paintRect);
}
}
```

Second, reference this CustomSeekBar in the layout xml file as:

```
    <view class="com.example.seekbar.CustomSeekBar"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

Comment: if i m using this technique then how will i apply custom thumb from drawable folder ?